# Why does this code no longer work when I swap the array for a vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I created a simple "Menu" for an assignment, that would list numbered options that you could select to call functions.

Header file:

```
#ifndef MENU
#define MENU

#include <string>
#include <vector>

const int MAXCOUNT = 20;

struct menuItem
{
    void(*func) ();
    string descript;

};

class Menu
{
private:
    //menuItem mi[MAXCOUNT];
    vector<menuItem> mi;
    int count;
    void runSelection();
public:
    Menu();
    void addMenu(char *Description, void (*f) ());
    void runMenu();
    void waitKey();
};

#endif
```

everything was working fine, until I tried to swap out the array of menuItems in the data section so that it would be a vector of menuItems, and all of the sudden it doesn't work. It seems to be stopping in my addMenu function:

```
void Menu::addMenu(char *Description, void (*f) (void))
{
    if(count < MAXCOUNT)
    {
        mi[count].func = f;
        this->mi[count].descript = Description;
        count ++;
    }
}
```

But I don't understand what changed?

Comment: A vector requires you to add entries to it using `push_back`, `insert`, `emplace_back`, or `resize`, or when you initially construct the vector.  Where did you do that in your code?  Also, instead of `[ ]`, use `vector::at()` -- doing that would have immediately told you what the problem was.

Comment: please initialize the vector to a certain size so that it does not do anything crazy.

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna guess that this is your problem

```
Menu() {
     mi.resize(MAXCOUNT); // you don't have this.
}     
Menu() : mi(MAXCOUNT) { // or this
} 
vector<menuItem> mi { MAXCOUNT} ; // and clearly not this
```

therefore

```
if(count < MAXCOUNT)
{
    mi[count].func = f; // this is not valid because mi has a size of 0
    count ++;
}
```

Here's a way fix your problem (count member not needed anymore):

```
if (mi.size() < MAXCOUNT)
    mi.push_back({f, Description}); // this would be a fix.
```

Or resize the vector as explained before.

Comment: I would totally get rid of the `count` member.  Having extraneous variables to denote the count of items in a vector leads to more bugs.  Instead, just use `vector::size()` to determine the number of entries.

Comment: Yeah that's what I said xD.

Comment: Whoops, thank you. That was a really helpful. I included the mi.resize(MAXCOUNT) and it runs.

Comment: Alright, but don't forget what we said about the count member tho. It's not really needed.

Comment: Also, `Menu() : mi(MAXCOUNT) { }` would be the way to initialize the vector on construction of `Menu`, rather than calling `resize()`

Comment: Or vector<menuItem> mi { MAXCOUNT} and works with any constructor now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to access elements in your vector that have not been created. A `std::vector` starts out *empty* and you generally add new elements one by one to the end of the vector increasing its size each time.

Rather like this:

```
class Menu
{
private:
    vector<menuItem> mi;
    // int count; // no need for this, use mi.size()
    void runSelection();
public:
    Menu();
    void addMenu(char *Description, void (*f) ());
    void runMenu();
    void waitKey();
};

void Menu::addMenu(char *Description, void (*f) (void))
{
    menuItem item = {f, Description};
    mi.push_back(item); // add the new element to the end (back)
}
```